# Why Calling the theme path in a multinlingual site adds a language prefix?

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

In my template whenever I call the path to my theme in a particular language it adds a language suffix dir like **mysite.com/fr/sites/all/themes/mytheme** while I'm expecting a path without a prefix (e.g. **mysite.com/sites/all/themes/mytheme**).

I'm use `drupal_get_path()` or `path_to_theme()`.

How can I ensure I get the right path in my template?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [base_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7) and [drupal_get_path('theme', 'yourthemename')](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) functions to get correct path.

Example:

```
$output = base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'yourthemename');
```

Result:

```
/sites/all/themes/yourthemename
```